# Help me create a test stub for ABCS requester

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, bpel, oracle-soa

So here is an image of my ABCS. It is a requester ABCS which acts as an interface between a legacy system and EBS:

[image]

The steps are basically as follows:

1. Legacy system makes a request (let's say a creation of a trouble ticket).
2. We transform the ABM request to EBS request.
3. We invoke the EBS.
4. EBS sends response to ABCS.
5. ABCS sends an acknowledgement response to EBS.

I need to create a simple stub that could be used to test this ABCS BPEL with soapUI. Can somebody give me a general idea about how it should look? I'm looking for some simple BPEL diagram example maybe with some description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do?

If you want to test your implementation with a simulation of EBS, you could use the JDeveloper test tool.

If you have to test your BPEL from SoapUi, you are looking for a solution to create a mock which is simulating your EBS ?

Edit : The solution to build a mock :

- From a composite view, add a component (BPEL for eg) and choose the
  template "based on a wsdl" In the WSDL input field, click "find
  existing wsdl"
- From the SOA resource browser, on the upper part of the windows search from ressources of the application and select the interface used to invoke EBS (the reference of your previous BPEL) and valid the creation of the component
- You have to develop the implementation of your component in order to build a response to return
- now you have to wire your BPEL's reference to your mock, several solutions :

  - Delete the wire to the EBS import and make a new wire to your mock
  - Configure the export of EBS to call an import of your mock (your mock could be on an another composite)
  - build an ESB rule to route your EBS request to your mock in certain cases
  - configure your deploiement to replace the EBS import to your mock import

The first and the second solution are intrusive, you have to edit your SOA module to made your test.
The better way is to build your mock into another composite and to use the deployement plan to have a test environnement with your mock.

Comment: I want to test my ABCS with soapUI. So I probably need to create a mock which is simulating my EBS. But not sure how should BPEL diagram of this mock look.